# How to use Iphone native calendar in my application

Tags: iphone, calendar

I want to use native calendar to get date and time.How to use it programatically in my iphone application. If any one know please help me.

Answer (score 1):

Simple answer: You can't.

There are some classes around you can use that come quite close, the one I find best is here:

https://github.com/klazuka/Kal

Comment: I want to select time also from that is it possible.

Comment: then how can i? do you have any idea?

Comment: Progam it yourself in the above mentioned class :-) - or use a UIDatePicker with only time in addition to the calendar view.